# Scrollable text in a DIV of unknown size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, resize

I have this:

```html
<section>
  <div id="dont-scroll">
    Unknown content!
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="scroll-this">
      This part should be scrollable when
      the total content overflows the SECTION
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you can see I want the user to be able to scroll the content in the lower half, but not the upper.

I can achieve this by using "resize" events, checking the size of SECTION and "dont-scroll", etc.

However, is there an easier way today, using only CSS?

Comment: Give a fixed height to scrollable block and add `overflow-y: scroll`. This will work

Comment: @AkhilAravind Thanks, yes, but that is exactly what I do not want to do. Was I unclear?

Comment: @Leo Absolutely. All you mentioned was that you want people to scroll the lower part which is `#scroll-this`, so the above comment is the right answer.

Comment: Basically all you need to do is add `#scroll-this {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}` and it would work.

Comment: @Gosi I did mention some more things. But please see the answer from Fabrizio.

Comment: @Leo "An easier way" and chooses an answer using flex with so many lines of code instead of a 2 liner. Erm okay.

Comment: @Gosi Yes, using JavaScript instead (and tracking the events) is much more complicated.

Comment: @Leo Cool. Btw, it wasn't me who downvoted. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach using Flexbox

```css
body, html {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

section {
   height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

section > div {
   padding: 20px;
}

div:not([id]) {
   background: #d8d8dc;
   flex: 1;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="dont-scroll">
    Unknown content! <br />
    Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="scroll-this">
      This part should be scrollable when
      the total content overflows the SECTION
      <br /><br />
      
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   
          consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec 
          odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. 
          Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. 
          Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, 
          semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>

      ...


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

Example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/KKpPbQO)

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice solution. Now I just have to test if I can use this solution in a shadowRoot. The section is the lite DOM. (Maybe a new question.)

Answer (score 1):

Defining height of scroll-this id and using overflow-y: scroll will make scroll-this id scroll able

```
#scroll-this {
    height: 10px; //this can be as per your choice 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I used 10px because your content is too less.

> "This part should be scrollable when the total content overflows the
>   SECTION".

Scroll will show only if line breaking content is greater then provided height.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a misunderstanding. I mentioned the resize events etc to say that this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#scroll-this {
  height: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section style="width:200px">
  <div id="dont-scroll">
    Unknown content!
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="scroll-this">
      This part should be scrollable when the total content overflows the SECTION
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a misunderstanding. I mentioned the resize events etc to say that this is not what I want.